# Solve for rectangular A in AB = C

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen

- A, C are m x n rectangular matrix.
- B is a n x n square matrix.
- B is not symmetric.
- B, C are known
- AB = C.

What is a good way to solve for A?

CB<sup>-1</sup> works. But I vaguely remember that Gaussian elimination is faster than inverse for solving a system of linear equations.

What functions in Eigen3 should I use for this task?
Are there specific layout of memory that would make calculating this faster?

Thanks.

Comment: use a library, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @karakfa Eigen 3 is a library. wait. what library do you use? armadillo, blitz++, or intel mkl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `B` is square, then `LU` factorization is likely a good choice, then transpose the equation to exhibit a standard solve:

```
A.transpose() = B.transpose().lu().solve(C.transpose());
```